# What is the real use of DBT (data build tool) & Snowflake together?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, data-modeling, dbt

DBT is T in ELT, that's what I see in all the articles, blogs, and videos. I understand the concept of modeling in DBT in ways like whatever data modeling logic we create can be stored as a version for future reference. But I still have a few questions,

1. Is DBT only meant to store data modeling logic versions (along with
   model testing, preview, and all)?
2. If I'm creating continuous data
   transformation pipeline in snowflake, how DBT will help there (apart
   from creating a model and model constraint check)?

I understand real usage this way,

1. Use DBT model to create table/views in snowflake (which will help to version the changes).
2. Use Snowflake streams & tasks to continuously flow the data transformation and to create a mart.

Any expert thought?

Comment: dbt creates and populates objects such as tables and views - as do many different Snowflake technologies (stored procs, streams, etc.). So, at a high level, they are not complementary technologies, they are different solutions for achieving the same result

Comment: @NickW Yes, that's my understanding. but at the end data transformation in snowflake can be done through streams,tasks,etc correct? DBT can't help for that.

Comment: Correct. You can transform data using Snowflake functionality directly or using dbt -  you can’t use both in the same transformation process

Comment: @NickW If I want to transform the data using dbt, how can I schedule dbt model to run while data is flowing to snowflake?

Comment: By using a scheduler. If you are using dbt Cloud then it has its own scheduler - or you can use an external scheduler such as Airflow

Answer (score 3):

The project has two components:

1. dbt model - creation of views and tables
2. dbt run - run of the model hierarchy/DAG

Data ingestion is performed continuously via 3rd party tools.

---

As I understand the goal is to keep the model as-is within dbt but be able to run it as soon as possible when new data arrives to have it "fresh" for the end user.

Possibilities:

a) use only view materializations in dbt in the entire flow.
Views are evaluated during runtime so the new data will be available when it arrives to source/base table

b) schedule the dbt run for critical path([--select](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/node-selection/syntax)) in more frequent manner, effectively introducing micro-batching

c) wait for the new Snowflake feature called [dynamic tables](https://www.snowflake.com/blog/dynamic-tables-delivering-declarative-streaming-data-pipelines/)(previously known as "materialized tables") and dbt support to materialize as "dynamic tables"

```sql
CREATE [ OR REPLACE ] DYNAMIC TABLE 
  LAG = ' { seconds | minutes | hours | days }'
  WAREHOUSE = 
  AS SELECT
```

More at:

- [Snowflake Summit Session: Build Streaming Data Pipeline](https://www.snowflake.com/summit-sessions/)

> See how Snowflake is removing the boundaries between streaming and batch systems by providing native streaming pipeline capabilities. You'll learn about the latest features such as Snowpipe Streaming and **Materialized Tables**.

- [How to create near real-time models with just dbt + SQL](https://discourse.getdbt.com/t/how-to-create-near-real-time-models-with-just-dbt-sql/1457)

Comment: Your answer is worthwhile but it doesn't have insight into what I'm looking for. We have data ingestion through ADF, the question is how to continuously transform those data within Snowflake. We have different layers (raw, source, stage, mart) using DBT in snowflake, how to continuously move data across all these layer models and table/view down the line?

Comment: @DSA `the question is how to continuously transform those data within Snowflake`  and `the question is how to continuously transform those data within Snowflake` Described possibilities focuses solely on that and they all take into account that data has been loaded into Snowflake by third party tool. Let me reiterate: views approach: data is flowing into raw, then stage/mart - if there are only views the transformations are visible immediately(views are just queries resolved at runtime).

Comment: @DSA microbatching - running the dbt flow in much frequent manner, e.g. every x minutes for specific part of the model that requires "fast movement" to presentation("dbt run --select model+"), and lastly dynamic table which are going to be "refreshed" without help of "dbt run" with predefined LAG (assuming that all materialization in the path are either views or other dynamic tables)