# How exactly DBT models continuous works?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, data-warehouse, dbt

I learned to create models with different levels (raw, source, staging, mart) using DBT. I also created a few basic models with real data cases using DBT.

I have a snowflake as a data warehouse. I'm confused about how to auto-execute my DBT models when data is constantly flowing from the source.

i.e. I want to calculate production data through DBT models and on the other hand we have real-time PowerBI reports on top of those transformed data.

To be very specific,

- I have all the necessary models created in DBT.
- I'm doing some data transformation on the staging dbt layer.
- I have set up a data pipeline using ADF to snowflake.

How do I auto-execute my dbt models logic when data is continuously flowing to snowflake from ADF?

Comment: I have already answered your similar question [What is the real use of DBT (data build tool) & Snowflake together?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74785766/5070879)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the real use of DBT (data build tool) & Snowflake together?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74614872/what-is-the-real-use-of-dbt-data-build-tool-snowflake-together)

Answer (score 1):

If you want your DBT models to reflect the *current state* of your data, you have two options:

**OPTION ONE**

Materialise all your models as views, not tables. A view is ultimately just a saved query masquerading as a table.

The downside is that your 'real time' reports are going to be slower, because they need to execute a complex SQL query instead of just pulling data from a materialised table. But that's a trade off everyone has to wrestle with when determining materialisation strategy.

**OPTION TWO**

Accept that 'current' is a lie; there will always be some lag, and it's up to you to establish what is acceptable.

If hour old data is good enough, schedule DBT to run every hour. If day old data is good enough, schedule it daily.